# Codeigniter redirect() problem

Tags: session, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2

I have created a MY_Controller class to check for sessions.

My LoginController is checking the user information and if that is ok, I redirect the user to the PainelController. I use redirect so my url will be refresh with /localhost/painel instead of /localhost/session/login

The problem is that when I use redirect, I cannot access my session, only using load->view.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: I use a .htaccess, the one found on [CI Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/)

**EDIT**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->session->userdata('usuario')) {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

}
```

---

Piece of Login: extends CI_Controller

```
if( $rs )
            {

                $this->session->set_userdata('usuario', $usuario);//usuario is a object
                //$this->load->view('painel');//it works
                redirect('painel', 'location');//it doesn't
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('login', $data = array('mensagem'=>'Usuário ou senha inválidos.'));
            }
```

--

My Painel View

```
echo $this->session->userdata('usuario')->usuario_nome; //it works
only if I load->view('painel')
```

Even if I try to access this session value on my PainelController (extends MY_Controller) it won't work, will say:

```
Message: main() [function.main]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Usuario" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition
```

Comment: I was not getting one point in this? Is your session getting cleared on its own after a redirect?

Comment: If so, I don't no why and how because when I use load->view it works properly,only redirecting gives me this problem

Comment: You can check if its getting cleared or not by echoing some session variable.

Comment: So you can access your session??

Comment: and you have a controller called painel?

Comment: Yes, I have a controller called painel

Comment: @Gerep It seems that this some sort of limitation on the CI's core. :|
That it works when you load the view, but on redirecting, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried redirecting a couple of times on my CI sandbox but I didn't lose my session.
 What libraries/helpers are you using in `PainelController`?
It seems you don't have `@session_start();` in that particular controller.

Usually, you can use existing `Auth` libraries that will handle this for you, and then include this in the constructor of every `controller` that or even in `MY_Controller`.
Here's an example:

```
class Events extends CI_Controller {
// Constructor function
public function __construct()
{
    //load initial models and libraries that are needed for the controller
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('auth');
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then my `auth` library would have a constructor like this.

```
class Auth {
  var $CI       = NULL;

  function Auth($props = array())
  {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    // Load additional libraries, helpers, etc.
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
    $this->CI->load->database();
    $this->CI->load->helper('url');
    @session_start();
  }
  ...
}
```

EDIT:

You can also include this in your `autoload` usually located at `config/autoload.php`. 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Here's an example.

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
| or in your application/libraries folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session', 'encrypt');
```

Comment: CodeIgniter's session library does `session_start` for you.

Comment: That's why I asked for his libraries, but it seems he doesn't. Usually having an `auth` library for handling restriction or permissions is better instead of redundant session authentication in every controller or method.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'll have to load auth library on every controller

Comment: You don't have to. There's the autoload config. I'll add this to my answer. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html